# Jenkins: how to run an exe on a remote computer

Tags: jenkins

I just started using Jenkins. Still not familiar with all its features.
I would like to run a Ranorex test which is on a remote computer. How can I do that from Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute binaries on a specific host, you can use slaves.

Here is a guide to setup master and slave on windows:f
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows

You will run the slave on the remote computer and connect it to the master.

To run the slave on your remote computer, you have to download the slave.jar and start it on the remote computer. This is described in the wiki article above.

You have to ensure, that your job is executed on the slave. This can be done by labels. You configure a label on the slave and configure the same label on the job too.

Comment: Do I need to configure or install something on the Slave computer?